# How to append data to an existing file

Tags: file, append, chapel

In Chapel, we can open a file for writing by using [`open()`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.open) + [`iomode.cw`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.iomode), e.g.,

```
var fout = open( "foo.dat", iomode.cw );   // create a file for writing
var cout = fout.writer();                  // make a channel
cout.writeln( 1.23 );
cout.close();
fout.close();
```

or making a channel by [`openwriter()`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.openwriter) as

```
var cout = openwriter( "foo.dat" );
cout.writef( "n = %10i, x = %15.7r\n", 100, 1.23 );
cout.close();
```

but there seems to be no option corresponding to "append" mode (in the [IO](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#io) page). Is this currently not provided, and if so, is there any idiomatic way to open a file and append data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append mode for IO is not supported as of Chapel 1.20. Until it is supported, you can use the following work-around:

```
// Open a file for reading and writing
var fout = open("foo.dat", iomode.rw);

// Position a writing channel at the end of the file
var cout = fout.openAppender();

cout.writeln(1.23);

cout.close();
fout.close();

/* Create a writer channel with a starting offset at the end of the file */
proc file.openAppender() {
  var writer = this.writer(start=this.length());
  return writer;
}
```

There is an open feature request for append mode in the Chapel GitHub issues. See issue [#9992](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/9992) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! the code worked fine on my computer (given that foo.dat already exists).